# How to act on the label control of a mouse down in OS X

Tags: swift, macos

In my class ViewController:  NSViewController

I have the following code:

```
@IBAction override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {

    self.myLabel.textColor = NSColor.redColor()
    //either of these work to set the labels text value
    self.myLabel.objectValue = "Hello World"
    self.myLabel.stringValue = "This is a test"

    switch(self) {
    case self.myLabel:
        //change text of myLabel
        break;
    case self.myLabel1:
        //change text of myLabel1
        break;
    case self.myLabel2:
        //change text of myLabel2
        break;
    }

}
```

This works to change the text and color of a Label Control called myLabel, but I have 3 Label controls on the View how do I change the color on the one that sends the mouse down event? The only way I can think to do it is with the switch statement as in the code above. But I think there is a better way by some how using the sender of the event?

I'm new to OS X and Mac development and come from the .NET C# world so thanks for helping this Mac noob! Using the latest Swift and Xcode.

Comment: Actually I just tried the switch(self) and it does not work blows up at runtime?

Comment: Basically my question boils down to: if you have several label controls on a view and you do a mouse click on that label control how do you detect which control you clicked on and modify the text or color of that label control in code? In my mouseDown function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure out how to determine if one of my NSTextField controls was clicked on in the mouseDown event of the view:

```
@IBAction override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {

    var event_location: NSPoint!
    event_location = theEvent.locationInWindow

    self.mouseDownEvent = theEvent

    var cntrl_id = NSTextField()
    var cntrl_frame = NSRect()
    var cntrl_name = String()
    var cntrl_value = String()
    var hit = Bool()

    for view in self.view.subviews as [NSView] {
        if let ct = view as? NSTextField {
            cntrl_name = ct.identifier!
            cntrl_id = ct
            cntrl_frame = ct.frame
            cntrl_value = ct.stringValue
            hit = cntrl_frame.contains(event_location)
            if hit {
                controlToMove = cntrl_id
                break
            }
        }
    }


}
```

There are probably ways to make this more efficient possibly such as keeping a dictionary of all the NSTextField controls on the view, and then
check the dictionary for if I have a "hit" on one of the controls.